# JQl - how to find linked issues in an issue

Tags: testing, report, jira, jql

Iam looking for the Jira JQL syntax, to find the linked-issues in an Issue. For example in Bug-issue i need to have in my report the linked-issues to my Bug-issue!

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to groovy script?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question well, you are looking for a `JQL` that will fetch you all the bugs that are **LINKED** to that specific bug!!! Considering this is what you're asking, here is the solution for that:

You'll need to create a filter as like what is shown below, and name this filter as `MyFilter`:

```
issuetype = Bug AND issuekey = ABC-12345
```

Then you will have to use this filter in the next filter to get all the linked issues (bugs) to the current bug:

```
issuetype in (Bug) and issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf('filter = MyFilter')
```

Using the second filter, you should be getting all the linked bugs to the original bug.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, I get "Field 'issueFunction' does not exist or you do not have permission to view it."

Comment: @HewWolff, try this with a different user login may be? The user with which you're trying to run this JQL might not have access to use functions or restricted by design.

Comment: `The "linkedIssuesOf" JQL function [is] provided by "Adaptavist Scriptrunner"`; it's not a native function in jira